# About the performance of ResNext architecture

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, resnet

I recently tried to improve a model which had basic ResNet blocks with gated CNNs in it by replacing them with ResNext blocks. It reduced model parameters from `22059265` to `17488129` which is a big parameter reduction. Even though this reduced the parameters, it didn't reduce the training time, in fact, it increased the time from `1e+02` to `2.6e+02`.

Following are the two implementations

**ResNet**

```
class RNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in, out, kernel, stride, padding):
        super(RNet, self).__init__()

        self.c1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv1d(in_channels=in, out_channels=out, kernel_size=kernel, stride=stride,
                      padding=padding),
            nn.InstanceNorm1d(num_features=out, affine=True))

        self.c1_gate = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv1d(in_channels=in, out_channels=out, kernel_size=kernel, stride=stride,
                      padding=padding),
            nn.InstanceNorm1d(num_features=out, affine=True))

        self.c2 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv1d(in_channels=out, out_channels=in, kernel_size=kernel, stride=stride,
                      padding=padding),
            nn.InstanceNorm1d(num_features=in, affine=True))

    def forward(self, input):
            first = self.c1(input)
            first_gate = self.c1_gate(input)
            first_GLU = first * torch.sigmoid(first_gate)
            second = self.c2(first_GLU)

            return input + second
```

**ResNext**

```
class GroupConv1D(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, padding, stride, groups):
        super(GroupConv1D, self).__init__()

        if not in_channels % groups == 0:
            raise ValueError("The input channels must be divisible by the no. of groups")
        if not out_channels % groups == 0:
            raise ValueError("The output channels must be divisible by the no. of groups")

        self.kernel_size = kernel_size
        self.stride = stride
        self.padding = padding
        self.groups = groups

        self.group_in_num = in_channels // groups
        self.group_out_num = out_channels // groups
        self.conv_list = nn.ModuleList([])

        for i in range(self.groups):
            self.conv_list.append(nn.Conv1d(in_channels=self.group_in_num, out_channels=self.group_out_num, kernel_size=kernel_size, stride=stride, padding=padding))

    def forward(self, inputs):
        feature_map_list = []
        for i in range(self.groups):
            x_i = self.conv_list[i](inputs[:, i * self.group_in_num: (i + 1) * self.group_in_num])
            feature_map_list.append(x_i)

        out = torch.concat(feature_map_list, dim=1)
        return out


class RNext(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in, out, kernel, stride, padding, groups):
        super(RNext, self).__init__()

        self.group_1 = nn.Sequential(
            GroupConv1D(in_channels=in, out_channels=out, kernel_size=kernel, stride=stride,
                        padding=padding, groups=groups),
            nn.InstanceNorm1d(num_features=out, affine=True))

        self.group_1_gate = nn.Sequential(
            GroupConv1D(in_channels=in, out_channels=out, kernel_size=kernel, stride=stride,
                        padding=padding, groups=groups),
            nn.InstanceNorm1d(num_features=out, affine=True))

        self.c2 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv1d(in_channels=out, out_channels=in, kernel_size=kernel, stride=stride,
                      padding=padding),
            nn.InstanceNorm1d(num_features=in, affine=True))

    def forward(self, input):
            first = self.group_1(input)
            first_gate = self.group_1_gate(input)
            first_GLU = first * torch.sigmoid(first_gate)
            second = self.c2(first_GLU)

            return input + second
```

I need to know what causes this increase in time. Is it because of the for loop? Can I also know whether the ResNext implementation with group convs(as mentioned above) is the best way to create this model?

Comment: Well, there not the same model right? What makes you think they would behave the same way in terms of inference time?

Comment: Yeah, they are different but in the ResNext [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.05431v2.pdf) they mentioned that their model is less complex than ResNet, and also for my model, it reduced model parameters from 22059265 to 17488129. And my thought was that the reduced number of parameters would result in a decrease in training time.

Comment: I'm not aware of the differences between the two models, but one thing is sure less parameters doesn't necessarily mean an increased speed. Just look at fully connected networks vs convolutional networks (shared parameters means less learned parameters but the compute time is usually longer *per-layer*). Same goes for CNN vs transformers.